# Compare 2 database

Tags: mysql, database-comparison

I have 2 identical databases. abc15 and abc18. But one of the database has one extra table and I need to find that. I thought the following query should return it, but is it not showing the record that I expect.

```
select * from information_schema.tables as a
    left join information_schema.tables as b
        on a.TABLE_SCHEMA=b.TABLE_SCHEMA AND a.TABLE_NAME=b.TABLE_NAME
    where a.TABLE_SCHEMA = 'abc15' AND b.TABLE_SCHEMA='abc18' and
        b.TABLE_NAME IS NULL
```

Comment: Your query is only going to check one direction, what happens when the new "table" is in the "b" database?  Switch to a outer join.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
$ mysqldumpslow --database abc15 >/tmp/a
$ mysqldumpslow --database abc18 >/tmp/b
$ diff /tmp/a /tmp/b
```

Answer (score 3):

What if database b has the extra table?  Try a full outer join and an extra constraint at the end (OR a.TABLE_NAME IS NULL)